# ¿Cómo puedo crear un vector que enumere las filas?

Tags: r

Sobre la base de datos iris tengo que crear un vector que actúe como el Identity de ella.(que contenga los # números del 1 hasta el número de filas de iris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con R base puedes crear un vector que vaya desde 1 hasta el numero de total de filas

La función `dim` devuelve las dimensiones de un df, la cual puede ser usada asi:

```
iris$filas = 1:dim(iris)[1]
```

Usando `tidyverse` puedes usar la función `row_number()`

```
iris %>% mutate(filas = row_number())
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!